# Listview is not updated after sorting (windows phone)

Tags: sorting, listview, windows-phone

I have create a `DataModel` class which contains `INotifyPropertyChanged` method.

Then I assign `ListView.ItemsSource` to the Observable Collection of the DataModel.

If new item is added to the Collection, the ListView is updated correctly.
But when I try to sort the list:

```
IssuesList = new ObservableCollection<Issue>(IssuesList.OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList());
```

The ListView is not updated automatically (order not changed).
The ListView is only changed when I set ItemsSource for the listview again.

How can I make the ListView updates automatically when items order is changed?
Thank for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're deteaching the instance. An observable collection only fires updates to the UI if its elements were modified but not when you're replacing its instance.

What you will have to do is to raise the propertychanged event after you replaced the collection with the new sorted one. Depending on how you implemented the notifying event:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("IssuesList");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I understand what you said but I'm not sure how to implement it.
I defined a class called "Issue", and "IssueList" is initiated in MainPage.xaml.cs (sort method, too).
I only know how to reaise NotifyPropertyChanged for a property of class, not for a collection. Can you show me how?

Comment: No, I never defined a collection in a Model class (I'm a newbie). So what I need to do is add IssueList collection to the class an apply NotifyPropertyChanged fot it?